# SSRS report - footer with different height

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with two pages. Both have a footer but with different objects. The footer on the second page would have bigger height because of additional objects. Unfortunately, the first page would get a footer with extra height that messes up pagination. Any tricks to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: The only way is to not use headers and add them to the bottom of the page. You can put your page content in a rectangle sized to your page (minus margins, footer and headers) and set the Report ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to False. Then add another rectangle with your objects for the pseudo-footer area below the rectangle. The 2nd page rectangle would have the Page Break. Just remember to include the Margin size in your page height calculations.

Comment: How would I make sure that pseudo-footer is positioned where the real footer would be?

Comment: As Hannover stated, you create a rectangle in your report that is the size of the area that will contain main content of the page, the pseudo footer rectangle sits below this. It's the 1st rectangle that forces the 2nd one down the page.